# sort properties with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, css, function, explode, preg-replace-callback

So... All properties have been sorted perfectly

BUT

how can I replace (/merge) them back on to the original $css value ?

This code is pretty much self explanatory but I have add what I'm expecting to get just in case... Small tweak needed here :)

```
<?php

function mySort($arr) {

    $arr = explode( ";" , $arr);
    sort($arr);
    array_shift($arr);

    $returnMe = NULL;

    foreach ($arr as $key) {
        $returnMe .= $key.';';
    }

unset($arr);

    return $returnMe."\r\n";

}

$css = <<<EOF

body {
z-index:9;
padding:0;
margin:0;
line-height:10px;
}

p {
z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
}

EOF;


echo '<pre>'.
    preg_replace_callback( '~.*?{(.*?)}~s',
        function ($match) {
            return mySort( $match[1] );
            }
        ,$css )
    .'</pre>';
```

I'm expecting to get :

```
body {
line-height:10px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index:9;
}

p {
font-size: 10px;
z-index: 9;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
border: 0 none;
font-size: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're matching the CSS selector but aren't adding it back into the returned value - it's just being replaced by the callback function

So what you need to do is capture those parts too, and return them from the callback, like this:

`echo '<pre>'.
preg_replace_callback( '~(.*?{)(.*?)(})~s', function ($match) {
    return $match[1] . mySort( $match[2] ) . $match[3];
}
,$css )
.'</pre>';`

Comment: Yes I know that and this is exactly what I'm asking ;)

Comment: Yea but $match[0] return the property and the unsorted selector of the css

Comment: I've added a code fragment as a concrete example, I don't use match[0], I capture the other bits separately and concatenate them.

Comment: Opps :) Yea!  You are absolutely right !!! Superb !!! Thank you soooooooo much !!!!